# Awk/sed solution for replacing/prepending subset of lines in between 2 patterns

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I would like to use sed/awk to only edit/prepend specific lines in between two patterns (EAST_40_1_EP00 &Arr and #pchan 5). Here is the block of text:

```
   EAST_40_1_EP00 &Arr{            # template for 6-channel units at BRTT 
                            #       nothing specified means to use global parameters
            pchan_map &Arr{         #These map q330 physical channels to SEED net-sta-chan-loc codes
            #       pchan   net_sta_chan[_loc]      calib   calper  segtype 
                     0       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHZ_00    $DB
                     1       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHN_00    $DB
                     2       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHE_00    $DB
                     0       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHZ_00    $DB
                     1       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHN_00    $DB
                     2       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHE_00    $DB
                     3       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHZ_01    $DB
                     4       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHN_01    $DB
                     5       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHE_01    $DB
                     3       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHZ_01    $DB
                     4       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHN_01    $DB
                     5       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHE_01    $DB
            }
            acq_matrix &Tbl{                                # acquisition matrix
            #       str0 str1 str2 str3 str4 str5 str6 str7 
            #       1    10   20   40   50   100  200  
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 0
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 1
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 2
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 3
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 4
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 5
            }
    }
```

I would like to add comment tags "#' to lines 11-16, and 24,26 using sed/awk, so the block of text looks like:

```
  EAST_40_1_EP00 &Arr{            # template for 6-channel units at BRTT 
                            #       nothing specified means to use global parameters
            pchan_map &Arr{         #These map q330 physical channels to SEED net-sta-chan-loc codes
            #       pchan   net_sta_chan[_loc]      calib   calper  segtype 
                     0       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHZ_00    $DB
                     1       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHN_00    $DB
                     2       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHE_00    $DB
                     0       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHZ_00    $DB
                     1       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHN_00    $DB
                     2       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHE_00    $DB
            #         3       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHZ_01    $DB
            #         4       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHN_01    $DB
            #         5       $DLNET_$DLSTA_BHE_01    $DB
            #         3       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHZ_01    $DB
            #         4       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHN_01    $DB
            #         5       $DLNET_$DLSTA_LHE_01    $DB
            }
            acq_matrix &Tbl{                                # acquisition matrix
            #       str0 str1 str2 str3 str4 str5 str6 str7 
            #       1    10   20   40   50   100  200  
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 0
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 1
                    m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 2
            #        m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 3
            #        m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 4
            #        m1   0    0    m40  0    0    0    0  # pchan 5
            }
    }
```

I don't mind executing two separate commands if I have to, but one would be ideal. I have two commands to grab out the subset lines, but am unsure how I can modify them to make it edit the actual file for those lines:

```
  sed -n "/EAST_40_1_EP00 &Arr/,/#pchan 5/p" q3302orb_test.pf | sed -n '11,16p' | awk '{print "#"$0 }' file

  sed -n "/EAST_40_1_EP00 &Arr/,/#pchan 5/p" q3302orb_test.pf | sed -n '24,26p' | awk '{print "#"$0 }' file
```

Can someone help me out with how I would 1) combine these commands into one command, and 2) edit the file itself not just print out the lines. I've tried using the -i command in various places with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  alpha[11] alpha[12] alpha[13] alpha[14] alpha[15] alpha[16]
  alpha[24] alpha[26]
}
/EAST_40_1_EP00 &Arr/ {
  bravo = 1
  charlie = NR
}
/#pchan 5/ {
  bravo = 0
}
bravo && NR-charlie+1 in alpha {
  $0 = "#" $0
}
1
```

1. Set array of good lines
2. Once start marker is found, save it
3. Also save line number of start marker
4. Set stop marker
5. Between markers, if line number is good, add comment
6. Print

Comment: Thanks so much Steven! This worked great! All I had to do was add in alpha[25] to get it to work for all of the lines!

Comment: Steven, I'm trying to add these lines into my script without creating an external script that's called by my the main script. I've tested what I thought would be the translation of this to a single line call, but it works unreliably, what do I have incorrect?                                                            awk 'BEGIN {alpha[11] alpha[12] alpha[13] alpha[14] alpha[15] alpha[16] alpha[24] alpha[25] alpha[26]} /EAST_40_1_EP00 &Arr/ {bravo =1 charlie == NR} /# pchan 5/ {bravo =0} bravo && NR-charlie+1 in alpha { $0 = "#" $0 }1'

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what my issue was. Needed a semi-colon in between bravo and charlie in order to be able to define charlie appropriately. So modify above with {bravo =1; charlie = NR} to get code into single command line call.